# Use size classes to create different cells for uitableview cell xib

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, xib, size-classes

I am using xib to design the UI for my tableview cell. My app is universal. right now i am using 2 different xib files. one for iphone cell and one for ipad cell.

I am wondering if its possible to use only one xib file and use size class to create UI for tableview cell for iphone and ipad.

I tried it but the problem i am facing is, when i change the size class from regular height and regular width and then change the height and width of xib the same height and width appear in any height any width size class and vice versa. thus i am not able to keep the constraints properly